# After Doxygen update "Modules" in tree view disapeared

Tags: module, treeview, updates

I've recently run an update of doxygen from 1.9.5 to 1.9.8.
Since the update I'm missing the section "modules" in tree view and in the top menu.
There are no specific entries concerning this in the release notes.

Are there some wrong configurations in my project popping up now or is it a bug?

The doxigen files are listed below. Until the update the "modules" section has contained the chapters "System Functions", "Runtime Services", "Support Functions" and "Project-Libraries".

My project includes two main dox-files:
**- overview.dox**

```
/**

@mainpage
M1 API documentation \msysBuildVersion, generated on \commonDoxygenBuildDate at \commonDoxygenBuildTime with doxygen V\commonDoxygenBuildVersion


@section SECBASIC Basic Communication Concepts

@copybrief BASIC

See @ref BASIC.


 */
```

**- and modules.dox**

```
/**
@defgroup SYS System Functions
@{
    @brief This part of the API contains operation system functions.
@}

@defgroup RUNTIME Runtime Services
@{
    @brief This part of the API is about system services.

    @defgroup RES Resource Service
    @defgroup INF Information Service
@}

@defgroup UTIL Support Functions
@{
    @brief This part of the API contains helper functions useful for implementation user specific applications.
@}

@defgroup MYLIBS Project-Libraries
@{
    @brief This part of the API describes the available libraries.
@}

*/
```

As soon as I switch back to doxygen version 1.9.5 everything is back normal.